# dell vostro 5481 turns off instead of suspend

Tags: 20.04, suspend, dell, intel

My laptop turns off instead of suspending. Like if I took the battery out. Cannot see any differences on next startup.
Laptop model is Dell Vostro 5481, CPU is i5-8265U (Whiskey Lake), GPU from Intel. Current Ubuntu version is 20.04.6. Same behavior was on Ubuntu 18.04.
Sometimes the problem temporarily resolves itself with a system update.

I've tried some recipes from similar questions with no avail and unsystematically. I can see a lot of threads on Dell laptops but the problems are not exactly like mine.

I would love help with identifying the underlying issue.

Thanks!

Edit:

following the comment of richbi I've looked at the bios. There was a disabled block sleep option, so suspending should be enabled.
Then I tried to suspend with systemctl and it worked. Now suspending with the GUI and lid closing works as well.
I checked on system updates and none has happened between failed and successful suspends.

I diffed two excerpts from syslog files, one with failed suspend-resume and another with successful resume. Both were blocks between `[sleep-monitor] system is about to suspend` and `PM: suspend entry (deep)`. Couldn't see any significant differences, any extra warning messages in failed block.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Have you checked your BIOS settings to make sure that ACPI (sleep states) is enabled? Also, for testing purposes have you tried running `sudo systemctl suspend`? If so, what was the outcome? Finally, have you reviewed system logs for any indication of ACPI or PM issues? Please edit your answer directly to include this information. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your comment, richbi. I've tried to answer the questions in the edit. I don't know how ACPI or PM issues should look like, tried searching for them in syslog files and didn't find anything suspicious. I don't know how to continue the research since the problem resolved itself for now.

Comment: Sounds good. If your issue is resolved (give it a few days), please mark this question as answered so others can benefit from your resolution. Thanks